# fsecurity command error on netapp

Tags: security, user-permissions, netapp

I'm facing an issue while using fsecurity command on my 7-mode netapp :

```
netapp> fsecurity apply /vol/vol_C/.../security.conf -c
fsecurity: /vol/vol_C/.../security.conf (Line 2): Unable to parse the task.
fsecurity: /vol/vol_C/.../security.conf (Line 3): Unknown security type.
fsecurity: Unable to parse the definition file, quitting.
netapp>
```

Here is the content of the security.conf :

```
cb56f6f4
1,0,"/vol/vol_C/.../test.txt",0,"D:P(A;CIOI;0x1f01ff;;;Everyone)"
```

What's wrong with my command ? I've followed the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting file from UTF-8 to ANSI, with Windows carriage return (CRLF), and adding a blank line at the end of the security.conf file solved this issue.